# How to evenly divide a face when loop cut doesn't work

Tags: mesh, knife-tool

I have a face. It is rectangular, but has extra vertices linking it to surrounding faces. From what I've read, these extra vertices are likely the reason why loop cut (my go to tool for this type of thing) doesn't work.

Reading up on it, it seems the go to answer to work around this is the knife tool. However, it doesn't give me the fine control that I want. The knife tool will only give accurate cuts by snapping to the middle of an edge, unlike loop cut which can be used to make clean straight lines anywhere on a face.

Is there a way to make the knife tool more accurate so it can consistently make straight lines at any point on the face like loop cut normally does? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Knife tool can be constrained to angle with pressing C while tool is active. Though the angle (0, 45 or 90) is related to view coordinates, not world. So maybe it would help if you align viewport with the face via Shift+Numpad7 and use Knife tool then

Comment: Thanks! Should be very helpful as well <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example I started with a plane with 5 vertices, so loop cut doesn't work:

I selected the upper edge, pressed W to subdivide 3 times.

[image]

Make the same with lower edge, then select a pair of vertices and press J to connect and divide the face.

[image]